# Include constant in pod

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is it possible to include the contents of a constant in the POD for a module. Example:

```
use constant DEFAULT_URL => "http://www.example.com";
...
=item B<setUrl>

Change the URL to query. Default is [contents of DEFAULT_URL here]

=cut
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=714673), no this is not possible without some work.  You could write another script to generate the POD documentation, and that could include the variable.

Comment: Great link, thanks! I guess I will rephrase the documentation rather than trying generation/substitution...